# Flipping a matrix-like string horizontally

Tags: python, string, reverse

The goal of this function is to flip a matrix-like string horizontally.

For example the string: '100010001' with 2 rows and three columns would look like:

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

but when flipped should look like:

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

So the function would return the following output:
'001010100'

The caveat, I cannot use lists or arrays. only strings.

The current code I have written up, I believe, should work, however it is returning an empty string.

```
def flip_horizontal(image, rows, column):

   horizontal_image = ''
   for i in range(rows):

       #This should slice the image string, and map image(the last element in the 
       #column : to the first element of the column) onto horizontal_image.
       #this will repeat for the given amount of rows

       horizontal_image = horizontal_image + image[(i+1)*column-1:i*column]
    
   return horizontal_image
```

Again this returns an empty string. Any clue what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range function can be used to isolate your string into steps that represent rows. While iterating through the string you can use `[::-1]` to reverse each row to achieve the horizontal flip.

```
string = '100010001'
output = ''
prev = 0

# Iterate through string in steps of 3
for i in range(3, len(string) + 1, 3):

  # Isolate and reverse row of string
  row = string[prev:i]
  row = row[::-1]

  output = output + row
  prev = i
```

Input:

```
'100
 010
 001'
```

Output:

```
'001
 010
 100'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `[::-1]` to reverse each row of the image.

```
def flip(im, w):
    return ''.join(im[i:i+w][::-1] for i in range(0, len(im), w))

>>> im = '100010001'
>>> flip(im, 3)
'001010100'
```

Comment: Curious what w represents, the matrix will not always be a square matrix which is why we need parameters for rows and columns

Comment: w is width (number of columns). The number of rows (height) doesn't need to be specified.